# ActiveX on Windows 7 throws "Object doesn't support property or method" error

Tags: javascript, windows-7, activex

We have a third-party ActiveX. It seems to be working fine on a Windows XP machine (Internet Explorer 7). However, when we test on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (Internet Explorer 9), we receive an error message -- "Object doesn't support property or method '{methodname}'"

Anyone knows what could be causing this?

- Is there a problem with the OS -- security is tighter, therefore the assembly needs something?
- Is there a problem with the browser -- again, maybe security is tighter, therefore something in Tools >> Internet Options >> Security needs to be adjusted?

Thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<body onload="OpenActiveX()">
    <OBJECT id="OurActiveX" 
        name=”OurActiveX" 
        classid="clsid:43663B77-905C-4885-BC6B-4F57FE10A270" 
        VIEWASTEXT codebase="CS1504CAB.cab">
    </OBJECT>

    <script language="javascript">
        function OpenActiveX()
        {
            try
            {
                alert(document.OurActiveX.Echo("Hi I am here."));
                var sdata = document.OurActiveX.GetData();
                if(sdata == "0"){
                    document.getElementById("barcodes").innerHTML = "No barcodes found.";
                }
                else if( sdata == "1"){
                    document.getElementById("barcodes").innerHTML = "Could not find the barcode reader.";
                }
                else{
                    var adata = sdata.split(":");
                    document.getElementById("barcodes").innerHTML = adata[0] + "<BR/>" + adata[1];
                }
            }
            catch(Err)
            { 
                alert(Err.description);
            }
        }
    </script> 
<div id="barcodes" />
```

Comment: Without seeing any of the code used, it's pretty hard to say. That error can be caused by a vast number of situations.

Comment: You make an excellent point! I apologize. I have edited my question to include the HTML. Thank you for your guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that the control is not available on the machine. You can check the security settings of IE on the client machine and verify the following security settings of IE to "Prompt" or "Enabled":

1) Download signed ActiveX controls 
2) Run ActiveX Controls and plug-ins 
3) Script ActiveX controls marked safe for scripting

Protected Mode is On by default in Windows 7. [Turn the proected mode off](http://kb.dynamsoft.com/questions/541/How+to+turn+off+Protected+Mode+of+IE?) or try running IE as administrator can get rid of the security problem.

Also, if you are using 64-bit IE, you need to make sure that the control supports 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `document.OurActiveX`, because the `name` attribute in your HTML is broken (you've used a "smart quotes" in place of a normal double quote — if you look carefully, the syntax highlighting gives this away).

So, in fact, `document.OurActiveX` is `undefined`, and that's why you can't invoke any methods on it.

```
<OBJECT id="OurActiveX" name=”OurActiveX" classid="..."></OBJECT>
```

Becomes:

```
<OBJECT id="OurActiveX" name="OurActiveX" classid="..."></OBJECT>
```

Anyway, selecting DOM nodes like `document.someName` is highly antiquated and a little error-prone; get rid of the `name` attribute entirely and use `document.getElementById` to select the node, like you have elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX doesn't work with 64bit IE.